# Terrafrom Azure postgresql geo restore

Tags: postgresql, azure, terraform

I'm trying to code terraform to restore Azure postgresql from geo-redundant backup , is there a way not from local-exec ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the terraform resources - fairly certain there is not.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/